# Problema con contador de caracteres

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un contador de caracteres como Twitter, pero no esta funcionando y el error que tengo es que la pagina se tilda a tal punto que tengo que cerrar la pestaña porque no me deja ver el error en consola y no puedo ver donde esta el error.

```js
function getID(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

function innerHTML(id, result){
    return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
}

function contadorCaracteres(){
    setInternal(function(){
        var c = getID("txt");
        if (c.length > 50){
            innerHTML("txtVista", "Solo permite 50 caracteres");
        } elseif (clength > 10) {
            innerHTML("<span style="color: red;">txtVista</span>", c.length); //faltando 10, cambiar a color rojo
        } else {
            innerHTML("txtVista", c.length);
        }
    },0000);
}
```

```html
<div onload="contadorCaracteres()">
<textarea class="form-control" id="txt" rows="3" maxlength="920"></textarea>
<div id="txtVista"></div>
</div>
```

Agradezco la ayuda!

Comment: Porque pasas como argumento una sentencia html cuando la funcion `innerHTML` espera un id de un elemento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de `setInterval` no es necesario en este caso,ya que cada 1 segundo estarias revisando la cantidad de caracteres, aunque no haya entrada,lo mejor es capturar el evento `keyup` para saber cuando el usuario ingreso un texto, ahora llama  la función `contadorCaracteres()`, donde tomara el value del `textarea` y luego su largo.

```js
function contadorCaracteres() {
  var textArea = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  var c = textArea.length;
  if (c > 50) {
    document.getElementById('txtVista').innerHTML = "Solo permite 50 caracteres";
  } else if (c > 10) {
    document.getElementById('txtVista').innerHTML = '<span style="color: red;">' + c + '</span>';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('txtVista').innerHTML = c;
  }
}
var el = document.getElementById('txt');
el.addEventListener('keyup', contadorCaracteres, false);
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="txt" rows="3" maxLength="50"></textarea>
  <div id="txtVista"></div>
</div>
```

Algunos errores en tu codigo son:

- `setInternal` deberia ser  `setInterval`
- `"<span style="color: red;">txtVista</span>"` estas abriendo comillas dobles y en el atributo `style` tambien abres comillas dobles, debes tener cuidado, seria algo asi `'<span style="color: red;">txtVista</span>'`
- `innerHTML("<span style="color: red;">txtVista</span>", c.length);`, segun tu funcion el primer parametro es el id del elemento, y estas enviando texto html

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info, veo que tenia muchas cosas mal.